# spark on yarn, Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

it's a simple spark writen by python. I got "Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143" error. Here is my code and script to run this code.
 
The size of input dir is roughly 100GB. But if I use a small data file(3GB), it will work well.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="job_name")

data1 = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
d1 = data1.filter(lambda x: "a string" in x)
print d1.count()

sc.stop()

//-----------------------------------------//

input="xxxxx"
output="yyyyy"

hadoop fs -rmr $output
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --master yarn \
  --num-executors 100 \
  --executor-cores 2 \
  --driver-cores 2 \
  --executor-memory 8g \
  --driver-memory 4g \
  stat.py \
  $input \
  $output
```

So I wrote a hadoop streaming to do this job, and I got:

```
Error: Java heap space
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

it seems to be the same error with my spark code.

Now I suspect that there are maybe some records in input is too large.

/* 
* add at 2016-12-16
*/ 
my hadoop streaming is working ^-^, with config like this:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2.jar
   -D mapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
   -D mapreduce.map.memory.mb=3192 \
   -D mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=3192 \
   -D mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx2872m \
   -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx2872m \
   -D mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048m \
   -D mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb=512 \
   -mapper "mapper.py" \
   -file mapper.py \
   -input $input \
   -output $output
```

but my spark code still can not run, no matter how i tune it.
this is my config of spark code:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --master yarn \
    --num-executors 200 \
    --executor-cores 2 \
    --driver-cores 2 \
    --executor-memory 20g \
    --driver-memory 16g \
    --verbose \
    stat.py \
    $input \
    $output

Here is my spark-defaults.conf:
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead      4096
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead        4096
spark.memory.storageFraction    0.9
```

With these infomation, does anyone know how to tune spark.

Comment: What are your heap settings for YARN?  How about min, max container size?  Memory overhead for Spark executors and driver?  At first blush it appears the memory problem is not from your Spark allocation.  How much physical memory does each node have?

Comment: I will look at these param tomorrow. Now I found a line in one of file is 750MB, I think this line may be the trouble maker.

Comment: @tadamhicks I have update my question, add my streaming and spark config.